# Symfony2 cache:clear prduces trash on screen (Windows 10)

Tags: php, symfony, caching, windows-10

I want to setup a pretty big Symfony2 project on Windows 10. With some troubles (mainly related to setting up ZMQ for PHP and XDebug) I eventually have everything in place. Assets and database were set up without any errors, however when I try to warm up cache I end up with some garbage on screen:

[image]

Pretty much the same happens in web browser if I just remove cache manually and refresh site. I have no clue where that comes from (the same app runs just fine on linux). Any clue appreciated.